# Does offering a bounty still bump questions to the front page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, bump

According to the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), when a user starts a bounty,

> The question is immediately bumped to the top of the active question list.

I have three active bounties on MSO at the moment, and I don't think a single one of them caused its question to get bumped to the front page when I offered it. [The `/faq` entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) don't mention this behavior.

I do remember getting bumps for past bounties and was expecting bumps for these recent bounties. Was that feature disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was indeed a bug introduced by recent bounty changes (the notices, etc.).  It will be corrected in the next build, and questions will be bumped appropriately.

Answer (score 9):

So far as I'm aware, they are *supposed to*.

But I can't seem to make it happen. Tested it on Programmers.SE, just in case there was some Meta-specific thing happening.

Either this was changed without documentation, or this is a bug - I'm leaning toward the latter.