# Does editing still bump a question?

Tags: support, edits, bump

Many times in the past I've edited a somewhat recent answer—say, from 30 minutes ago—and noticed that the concomitant question didn't bump to the top.  I just confirmed it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314096/352552); the question is currently sorted in the JavaScript page based on when it was asked, not my edit.

I've **never** made edits just to bump a question to whore rep—my original answer was wrong which was why I fixed it—but my understanding is that the CW self-edit trigger exists to prevent  edit-then-bump-then-score-rep—profit! activity.

If non-ancient edits no longer bump a question, should the self-edit CW trigger be brought inline with this?  Should an answer be made CW if you make 10 edits **that actually bump the question**?

<sub>and to avoid any implication of impropriety, I'm already capped on SO, so I'm not looking for any sort of "meta effect" on my answer</sub>

Comment: Click on another view tab. Try **active** instead of **newest**

Comment: @random - all that time typing the question - blown away :)  -- thanks.  Can you put that in an answer so I can close?

Comment: sory but what is `bump` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, any and all successful editing will still bump the question. This has not changed (though we [have had recent errors with bumping that have been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/does-offering-a-bounty-still-bump-questions-to-the-front-page)).

As noted by [random](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random), you may have been looking at the wrong tab - only the 
**'Active'** tab shows these bumps; the purpose of that tab is to show new activity.

Comment: Bump it on the *Active* tab, as Random pointed out.  I only ever check the *newest* tab, which was the source of the confusion.  Thank you Grace.

Comment: Is the Active tab now called '[interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)'? Or is it just gone? **Edit**: Oh, [the Active tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) is on the [Questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions), not the [home page](http://stackoverflow.com/).