# Is it possible to push your unanswered question to the front page?

Tags: discussion, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I was wondering if it was possible to push your question on Stack Overflow back to the front if it has not been answered and not many people got a chance to see it

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not think of phrasing it that way so I did not come across that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways unanswered questions can get some lovin':

1. Make a sensible edit to your question. [Edits will bump your question onto the active tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114034/does-editing-still-bump-a-question).

   - make sure your edit improves your question. Try to identify why you have not been getting any answers and address the problem
   - be careful not to do this too often. Editing it 10 times will automatically convert it into a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).
2. [Put a bounty on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). That will place it in the featured tab as well as bump it to the front page.
3. [Share a link to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges) on social media sites to drive some attention to it. As a bonus, you'll stand a chance to earn some badges.
4. Pray that the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/the-community-user) picks your question. Pray really hard.

See also: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Thanks for all of the different ideas. Really appreciate it, and shall be sure to remember to use these in the future!

Answer (score 4):

Putting a bounty on the question will make it appear on the featured tab, and bump onto the front page of "active". Here's a [full list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) of things that happen when you put a bounty on a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance if you or someone else starts a bounty on it. It appears in the featured tab..

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your post, answer your own question, or set a bounty on it, it'll pop to the top of the active list.

Comment: So if my rep is too low to use bounty, I would be able to comment on it and send it back up on interesting?

Comment: @Russell "Commenting" isn't the same as "editing" or "answering".

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah i was looking over the options on the post and i tried commenting to bump it back up, but i see the edit option instead. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from trying to push your question to the front, you should also try to reach outside of the SO community and share the link via Twitter, Facebook, G+, etc. This'll help get you a better answer and might just bring more people into the community.

Comment: Ah well unfortunately my friends are not very skilled in any kind of programming.

Comment: @Russell Other people besides your friends can see things like Twitter posts--hashtags can get attention. Targeting an `@` user/group/list with related skills may get attention... depending on the target.

Comment: Hmm I did not think about that. Very good suggestion, although i am loathe to use twitter for anything. Seems it would be a good idea to make one. Thanks!

Comment: @Russell If you are loathe to use your "real" account, create an alias/handle. I know the corporations don't like this, but it's been a part of the interwebs for decades.

Comment: Good idea. I am not sure why corporations would be upset by it, but luckily I am interning for a small company so I won't have to worry about that. Thanks for the advice.